# WOW Slider "Book page" animation not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to use WOW slider's book paging animation for my website, but I notice that it does not seem to work as expected in Firefox. Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Anyone know if there is a simple fix for this, or should I rather just stay away from WOW slider.

Here is the link to their demo that does not work in firefox:
http://wowslider.com/css3-image-slider-book-demo.html

Comment: Please, specify your problem in more detail.

Comment: In Firefox the animation of the page turning is behind the slide instead of in front of it, as it shows in Chrome
http://wowslider.com/css3-image-slider-book-demo.html
Open the link in Chrome and look at the animation, then
Open the same link in Firefox and look at the animation